# AppleScript - wait for do shell script done

Tags: applescript

I write a Command Line Tool to fetch movie information from IMDB. It's in JavaScript and called movinfo. I run it in AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set movT to "Back-to-the-future"
    set exportPath to "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:;"
    set oriInfo to do shell script exportPath & "movinfo " & quoted form of movT
    return oriInfo
end tell
```

It works great. But sometimes movinfo takes long time to fetch the information from the Internet. So I want to add a function to check if the fetching is done or not. I try "ignoring...end ignoring" structure firstly:

```
tell application "System Events"
    ignoring application responses
        set movT to "Back-to-the-future"
        set exportPath to "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:;"
        set oriInfo to do shell script exportPath & "movinfo " & quoted form of movT
    end ignoring
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    repeat 30 times
        try
            return oriInfo
            exit repeat
        on error
            delay 1
        end try
    end repeat
    do shell script "killall System\\ Events"
end tell
```

But this doesn't work. Maybe I can do something with the Command Line Tool to do this job. But I really don't know too much about JavaScript, and CLI. I want to do this in AppleScript. 
Hope someone can tell me what's wrong with the code, or how to do this in AS?

Comment: Your entire System Events code is pointless. `do shell script` belongs to Standard (Scripting) Additions and doesn't send Apple Events. The basic design of AppleScript is synchronous because regular compiled scripts don't have a runloop. And also `do shell script` is supposed to run synchronous. Apparently the javascript is asynchronous  so there is the place to manage the timing.

Comment: @vadian, thanks, I do some googling about the DIFFERENCE between SYNCHRONOUS and ASYNCHRONOUS. They are new knowledge to me.

Comment: Synchronous means the code is executed serial on a single thread. Asynchronous mean the code is executed concurrent on multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I don't have the `movinfo` utility (you neglected to provide a link) so I can't test this, but it should work on face value.

First (as vadian pointed out in comments) you don't need the System Events tell blocks as you've used them, so I've restructured that. The trick here is to detach the movinfo utility so it runs as a process independent of the script, writing the movie info into a file at `~/movieInfo.txt`. The script then recovers the process pid from the `do shell script`, and waits for the utility to end, using system events to test if a process with that pid is still running. When the process ends,
the script reads the info from the file back into the `oriInfo` variable. For questions about the unix tricks, see: [Technote 2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-TNTAG5-I_WANT_TO_START_A_BACKGROUND_SERVER_PROCESS__HOW_DO_I_MAKE_DO_SHELL_SCRIPT_NOT_WAIT_UNTIL_THE_COMMAND_COMPLETES_).

```
-- set output file path
set movieInfoFile to POSIX path of (path to home folder from user domain) & "movieInfo.txt"

set movT to "Back-to-the-future"
set exportPath to "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:;"
-- run and detach utility, returning its process id
set procID to do shell script exportPath & "movinfo " & quoted form of movT & " &> " & movieInfoFile & " & echo $!"

repeat 30 times
    tell application "System Events"
        -- test if pid is still active
        set isStillRunning to count of (every process whose unix id is procID)
    end tell
    if isStillRunning = 0 then
        --not active, so proceed
        exit repeat
    else
        delay 1
    end if
end repeat

-- pull info from file 
set fp to open for access movieInfoFile
set oriInfo to read fp
close access fp
```

Comment: Great information. I searched "unix id of process on macos”. Nothing useful can be found in Google. On output screen of top command in terminal, I see words like “PID”, “PPID”, “UID”. They don’t looks like unix id. But I'll keep testing your code.

Comment: PID is process id, which System Events calls the `unix id`. PPID is the process id of the parent process (the process that spawned the process you're looking at). UID is the user id (the id of the user that owns the process).  It's all very confusing till you get used to it.